# why aggregate function (min) on custom field is always null?

Tags: soql

Why the min on 'Account.Number_Of_Contacts__c' would always return null whereas same function on standard field like 'Account.Name' works just fine. Is it a glitch ?

The query:

```
select min(Account.Name) NameOfAccount,  count(id)
ActualNumberOfContacts,  min(Account.Number_Of_Contacts__c) test  FROM
Contact GROUP BY AccountId
```

How to get what i'm looking for in a single query?

Comment: Hi @Gorr, Welcome to SSE ! Do you have the value for that field value for  custom field? If the field is null on Account that results in null value. As Account Name cannot be null so it is returning the value always.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my comments there is no issue in the query. The issue might be because Number_Of_Contacts__c field is having null value . If the field is having Null value then the min of Null would be Null.

As Account Name cannot be null so it is returning the value always irrespective of the Null values in other fields.